# How to save the column names and their corresponding type in R into excel?

Tags: r, class

i have a R data set with >200 columns. I need to get what class each column is and get that into excel, with col name and its corresponding class as two columns

Answer (score 1):

**1**. Using **lapply/sapply** with **stack/melt**

You could do this using `lapply/sapply` to get the `class` of each column and then using `stack` from `base R` or `melt` from `reshape2` to get the 2 column `data.frame`.

```
 res <- stack(lapply(df, class))
 #or
 library(reshape2)
 res1<- melt(lapply(df, class))
```

Then use `write.csv` or using any of the specialized libraries for writing to excel data i.e. `XLConnect`, `WriteXLS` etc.

```
 write.csv(res, file="file1.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

`.csv` files can be opened in excel

**2.** From the output of **str**

Or you could use `capture.output` and `regex` to get the required info from the `str` and convert it to `data.frame` using `read.table`

```
v1 <- capture.output(str(df))
v2 <- grep("\\$", v1, value=TRUE)
res2 <- read.table(text=gsub(" +\\$ +(.*)\\: +([A-Za-z]+) +.*", "\\1 \\2", v2),
                                 sep="",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

head(res2,2)
#                         V1     V2
#1                  t02.clase Factor
#2 Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1    chr
```

#### data

```
df <-structure(list(t02.clase = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AK", 
class = "factor"),Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1 = c("0", "0", "0"),
Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2 = c(0, 0.01303586, 0), Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3 =
c(0.051311597, 0.003442244, 0.017347593), Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Std_A_CLI_promociones = c(0.4736842, 0.5, 0), Std_A_CLI_dias_cliente =
c(0.57061341, 0.55492154, 0.05991441), Std_A_CLI_sucursales = c(0.05555556, 
0.05555556, 0.05555556)), .Names = c("t02.clase", "Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1", 
"Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2", "Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3",
"Std_A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4", "Std_A_CLI_promociones", "Std_A_CLI_dias_cliente",
"Std_A_CLI_sucursales"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: (+1) for the regex + `str` combinaiton

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks,I guess the `regex` bit is not needed as `lapply` method is more easier to use.

Comment: I think in the long term it could be way more efficient both memory and time wise. Especially if combined with one of `stringi`s functions. That could be quite useful function in some packages

Comment: @David Arenburg Yes, it could be.

Comment: BTW, did you test it on `factor` variables, I don't think it gives desired result

Comment: @David Arenburg I corrected it. Hope it works for other cases.